# SharePoint online 404 not found (_layout/15/1033/CloudApps/cloudapps_strings.js) error

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I'm getting following 3 errors in SP online apps:

1. /_layouts/15/1033/CloudApps/cloudapps_strings.js 404 (Not Found)
2. Refused to display 'https://portal.office.com/SuiteServiceProxy.aspx?exsvurl=1&realm=office365.com&Silent=1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
3. Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('https://portal.office.com') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null')

Due to this the custom action script link executes only once during page load and not in subsequent navigations.

PS: The embedded script further registers script tags in head section which do not load due to MDS.

Please let me know if any one has faced this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same issue as #1. This is only occurring on one particular subsite. I have opened a ticket with the SharePoint Online team.

Comment: any traction on this ticket? were you able to find the reason for this error?

Comment: My issue ended up being that the master page for one of the subsites was somehow changed. It was supposed to be set to inherent from my parent site since that's where all the jQuery and other scripts were being loaded.